# Comprehension Axiom and Intersections

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I'm reading Goldrei's very good self-study book, *Classic Set Theory*, and am confused by his remarks on the Comprehension (Separation) Axiom.  He says that one might naively think that the intersection of a and b exist if a and b do because one can form the set of all z, such that z is in a and z is in b.  But he says this won't work on the grounds that "we...need the zs to be 'separated' out of some set x."  I don't follow this reasoning.  Why isn't a itself such a set?

Comment: We do need more for union, but intersection seems unproblematic, easy use of Separation.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that Comprehension essentially said that if $\varphi(x)$ is a property, then there exists a set $X$ such that $x\in X$ if and only if $\varphi(x)$ holds.

This is useful, because mostly we want collections of mathematical objects to be yet again a mathematical object. But this is also problematic, as shown by the many paradoxes of naive set theory.

Separation is the limitation of Comprehension. We can't say that there exists $X$ like we did before. However, if $A$ is a preexisting set, then there exists $X$ such that $x\in X$ if and only if $x\in A$ and $\varphi(x)$ holds. We "separate" the elements of $A$ which satisfy a certain property.

So taking the property $x\in A\land x\in B$ is not enough, because we need to separate our elements from a preexisting set. But using the property $x\in B$, and separating the elements of $A$ with this property *does* work.

Comment: Thanks, Asaf.  But you seem to be saying what the author is denying (and what I was saying).  Author says that "[w]e can find a suitable set x by taking it to be a u b".  But you seem to be agreeing with me that, actually, we can just take either a or b, and then "separate out" the members of that set which are also members of the other.  Correct?

Comment: Yeah, using only $A$ should be enough.

Comment: OK, thanks, Asaf.